# Select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting '(', WITH

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Intento hacer una consulta y me aparece un error de sintaxis en el primer `SELECT`, según he leído el error no está en ese `SELECT`,sino en otro lugar, pero no encuentro donde.

```
   SELECT D.nombreDpto, COUNT(N.nDIEmp)
   FROM Departamento D, 
       (SELECT * FROM Departamento D
       NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN Empleado E
       )N
   WHERE D.codDepto = N.codDepto
   GROUP BY D.nombreDpto
   ORDER BY D.nombreDpto DESC;
```

Comment: Qué versión de MySQL estás usando?

Answer (score 0):

Hola supongo que estas tratando de sacar el número de empleados por departamento, puedes usar algo como esto para obtenerlo.

```
SELECT D.nombreDpto, COUNT(1)
   FROM Departamento D
        LEFT JOIN Empleado E ON E.codDepto = D.codDepto
   GROUP BY D.nombreDpto
   ORDER BY D.nombreDpto DESC;
```